# Получить viewModelScope из Hilt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger2, viewmodel

Мой класс

```
 class UserDataSource @Inject constructor(private val listService: ListService, private val scope: CoroutineScope): PageKeyedDataSource<Int, News>()
```

Мне нужно получить viewModelScope из ViewModel, Но всегда ошибка, как вытянуть что-то из ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас `UserDataSource` singleton или живёт дольше чем viewmodel, поэтому вам не следует вытянуть что-то из viewmodel. Так как в любое время viewmodel может умереть. У вас вылетит `nullPointerException` eсли вы будете обратиться к методу viewmodel после его смерти. Вместо viewmodel используйте repository, так как repo singleton(по идее). Кроме того viewmodel все равно использует repo чтобы загрузить данные, так что вам мешает использовать repo вместо viewmodel?